# The console I use in my browser when I test javascript is not displaying the error line in which the error occurred

Tags: javascript, console

Just to let you know, I usually open the index.html file when testing out the code because the javascript file does not open up in the browser. When trying to test my javascript code in the console using chrome dev tools, it sometimes displays an error, which is expected. Usually, with an error, there is a line that tells you the javascript file line in which the error occurred. Yet, when an error pops up on the screen, it does not display the line number, it displays the letters, VM, followed by three numbers, a colon, and then a number one; something like this: VMXXX : 1. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

What is the result in incognito mode?
Try with incognito and disable all plugin if there are some which are working in incognito mode and share the result here.

Comment: Hello, it displays the same thing, just with different numbers after the letters 'VM'.